# Adding extra column in Redshift using the copy command

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I want to add extra columns in Redshift when using a COPY command. For example I have a lambda which will get triggered whenever there is an event in s3 bucket so I want to insert the versionid and load_timestamp along with the entire CSV file. Is this something we can achieve using the COPY command?

I tried alot of things but nothing seemed to work

Kindly suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

The load_timestamp can be done by having a default value of getdate() for this column.  When the row is made and no value is inserted for this column the default value will be the timestamp when it was made.

The versionid will need to be some post processing step.  The typical way to do this is to COPY to a staging table and then insert on to the fact table with this data plus the versionid (and load_timestamp).

If you want to do only issue one SQL command from your Lambda you can wrap these steps up in a stored procedure.